# What performance can I expect from a simple query: Simple example is slow

Tags: python, postgresql, query-optimization

I am using a PostgreSQL database, which is hosted by an external company. The queries are much slower than I expected, and I need help to understand.

**Case**:  I have a single table, say *MainTable*, with about 15.000.000 rows. The table has 7 columns of types:

*(integer, integer, integer, datetime, datetime, datetime, float).*

The primary key consists of the two first integer columns, called *GroupId* and *ValueId*. I frequently need to extract all data from a single group. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE GroupId = 23.
```

There are about 50 groups in *MainTable*, each contains around 15000000/50 = 300,000 entries.

My concern is that the *select query* above takes around 4-5 seconds:

1. Is this really the expected performance?
2. If not, do you have any suggestions for how to improve the query? I already tried a table index on *GroupID*.
3. Can I calculate an upper limit for the expected performance, to understand how far from optimality I am?

My only knowledge on the SQL server is that is has 2GB of memory.

Here is the execution plan (with a simple index on GroupID):

```
Gather  (cost=5897.44..260656.04 rows=261275 width=44) (actual time=33.456..126.031 rows=227646 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=2755
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on data  (cost=4897.44..233528.54 rows=108865 width=44) (actual time=11.099..34.584 rows=75882 loops=3)
        Recheck Cond: (group_id = 915)
        Heap Blocks: exact=492
        Buffers: shared hit=2755
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx  (cost=0.00..4832.12 rows=261275 width=0) (actual time=32.792..32.793 rows=227646 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (group_id = 915)
              Buffers: shared hit=626
Planning Time: 0.064 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 6
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
  Timing: Generation 0.851 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.000 ms, Emission 0.000 ms, Total 0.851 ms
Execution Time: 145.180 ms
```

Comment: Performance is likely not driven by the database itself, but by serializing/transferring/derserializing the results. It seems questionable to me that you try to dump 300k rows in that query. Maybe think about your business logic behind that.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have added the execution plan. Does this help.

Comment: And what kind of network between the server and client

Comment: Your query only takes 145 **milli**seconds. (0.15 seconds). So the 5 seconds you are experiencing is the time it takes to send 227646 rows from the database server to your application (or SQL client) and the processing those rows there. The database is not the bottleneck. Are you by any chance using pgAdmin? It is know to be very slow when displaying data - especially large results like that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am actually using Python to fetch the data via pandas, and this is really slow (4-5). Then I went to pgadmin to try make the call directly and it was also 4-5 seconds. But maybe the slow performance in python is due to something else then? Do you have a good  alternative to pgadmin? And do you think Python could be the reason the query is slow?

Comment: pgAdmin is programmed in Python if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Looks like an application or network problem, that's taking about 98% of the time spend: 145 milliseconds inside the database vs 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) your facing in your application

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is very decent performance, given that you select 227646 rows.  You are lucky that the correlation is high (the rows are all stuck together in a comparatively small number of 8kB blocks) and everything was cached, otherwise performance would be much worse.